# Passing a list and lookup first (non empty) match in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c'],
                   "B":['he','she',None,'I',None,None,'them','our']})
```

and I have a list

```
lst = ['a','b','c']
```

I would like to filter the dataframe (or get a dictionary) where only the first matching value in column "B" is returned.

```
my_dict = {'a':'he', 'b':'I','c':'them'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `dropna`, `drop_duplicates`, convert to Series and then `to_dict`:

```
lst = ['a','b','c']

my_dict = (df.dropna(subset=['B'])
             .drop_duplicates(subset=['A'])
             .set_index('A')
             .loc[lst, 'B'].to_dict()
           )
```

Alternative:

```
my_dict = df.dropna(subset='B').groupby('A')['B'].first().to_dict()
```

output: `{'a': 'he', 'b': 'I', 'c': 'them'}`

Comment: Thanks Mozway, I got this error when running both your line - Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'B' was passed

Comment: wrap the subsets in a list (this is for older pandas)